# How to create uneditable / locked regions in templates in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I have created a template file in my project which I want to apply to almost all pages in my website/project.

Ideally I would like there to be editable regions and uneditable/locked regions in the template, so that when I update the code in the template it should update all the uneditable regions in the pages that use this template.

For example, in Dreamweaver, you can do this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="title" -->
<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
</title>
<head>
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="head" -->
<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
</head>
```

The `<title>` and `<head>` areas remain editable for any page and won't be overwritten when a template file code changes. However if I was to remove the `<html>` tag then that would be removed for all pages using the template.

Can I achieve this in IntelliJ IDEA at all?

Comment: I suggest this question focusses on one editor, and since an answer has arrived for IntelliJ IDEA, it should be that one. On Stack Overflow, questions that ask several questions are hard to grade - can a good answer to just one of them be the "right" answer? Long-term readers also want to steer questions in the direction of what would be useful to other readers - people may well be interested in what IDEA can do, but they would be much less likely to want to know how to do it in two different IDEs.

Comment: Thus, if you need to separately know the answer to this question for another editor, would you ask a new question?

Comment: @halfer I accept your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IntelliJ IDEA consider using [Structural Search and Replace](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html) - to find and replace some common code pattens or code templates. See [Searching for XML and HTML tags, attributes, and their values](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace-examples.html#xml) for examples.